# Content Inside a Shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to get my footer to look like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sp7R.jpg). 4 columns inside a triangle shape.

[image]

However for some reason it appears that all four columns get stacked on-top of each other, which I confirmed by slight changing the top margin. When I comment out the `#right_triangle`, I get 4 columns, as you would expect. I believe its the border on the actual triangle that's doing it, but I cant figure out a way to do it or get around it.

Below is the code I'm using.

```css
#right_triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 300px solid #009933;
  border-right: 2000px solid transparent;
}
#footer_column1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
#footer_column2 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
#footer_column3 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
#footer_column4 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="right_triangle">
    <div id="footer_column1">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column2">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column3">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column4">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change **float:left;** to **float:inline** all three statements.

Comment: @ArifBurhan There is no such value as `inline` for `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

The problem as you've correctly guessed is with the `#right_triangle` but it is not because of border. It is because of `width: 0` on this element and `width: 25%` on child `#footer_column*` elements. May be you overlooked it (or maybe you haven't understood the concept fully) but a percentage width on a child element would use the parent's set width as reference for calculation. Thus the `width` of all child elements are nothing but `0px`. Since they are floated, the second and subsequent elements are offset from their previous sibling only by the width of the previous element(s) and they don't have any margin on the right also. So, effectively they are all placed at 0px on the left (on top of each other).

Again since they are floated they stay in same line unless their width exceeds a line's width. Here the width is also not more than a line's width (which is the parent's width). If you set even `width: 1px` to any of the first three elements, you'd notice that the others get pushed to the next line.

---

**Solution:**

Given how you need the screen's width to be split evenly across the 4 columns (from the image) and without changing your overall approach, you could make use of any one of the following solutions:

1. Give all the `#footer_column*` elements, a `width` in viewport units instead of in percentages, set `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and add `white-space:nowrap` to the parent. All these will make them get displayed on the same line ***without changing your markup***.

   ```css
   #right_triangle {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     border-bottom: 300px solid #009933;
     border-right: 2000px solid transparent;
   }
   #footer_column1 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25vw;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #footer_column2 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25vw;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #footer_column3 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25vw;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #footer_column4 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25vw;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="footer">
     <div id="right_triangle">
       <div id="footer_column1">Hello</div>
       <div id="footer_column2">Hello</div>
       <div id="footer_column3">Hello</div>
       <div id="footer_column4">Hello</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Make all the 4 footer column elements as children of footer element instead of `#right_triangle`. Since the footer is a block element, it gets 100% of the screen width by default and so it would be split evenly across the 4 children. Note that you would have to absolutely position the `#right_triangle` and use `z-index: -1` on it for this method.

   ```css
   #footer {
     position: relative;
   }
   #right_triangle {
     position: absolute;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-bottom: 300px solid #009933;
     border-right: 2000px solid transparent;
     z-index: -1;
   }
   #footer_column1 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
   }
   #footer_column2 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
   }
   #footer_column3 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
   }
   #footer_column4 {
     margin-top: 200px;
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="footer">
     <div id="right_triangle"></div>
     <div id="footer_column1">Hello</div>
     <div id="footer_column2">Hello</div>
     <div id="footer_column3">Hello</div>
     <div id="footer_column4">Hello</div>
   </div>
   ```

---

**Notes:**

- Using CSS `transform` for achieving the triangle in this question would be tough because it will require specific angle calculations for both `skew` and `rotate` (depending on which one is used) and hence not recommended.
- Gradients could have been a good option for this one but unfortunately they get rough and jagged edges at very high dimensions and hence not recommended.
- If you ***can change your overall approach***, I'd ***recommend using SVG to create the triangle***. It is not that SVG offers any great advantage for this particular shape but it is generally more useful to start learning and using SVG for shapes as it helps in creating a lot of complex ones with ease. Below is a snippet using SVG.

  ```css
  #footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  #right_triangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  #right_triangle path {
    fill: green;
  }
  #footer_column1 {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  #footer_column2 {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  #footer_column3 {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  #footer_column4 {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="footer">
    <svg id="right_triangle" viewBox='0 0 2000 300'>
      <path d='M0,0 2000,300 0,300z' />
    </svg>
    <div id="footer_column1">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column2">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column3">Hello</div>
    <div id="footer_column4">Hello</div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Im a newbie which explains why i missed the width set to zero, that makes a lot of sense why then it wouldn't work. Thanks for you help

Comment: Oh I see, that explains it. Its alright as we all start from zero :) Glad that I could help.